# How to set sender in Outlook POP account using AppleScript?

Tags: outlook, applescript, outlook-for-mac

This script selects my main account and the signature related to it.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
set theContent to "Mail Content etc."
set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties   {subject:(("Month ") & (do shell script "date '+%m'")), content:theContent}
make new recipient with properties {email address:{address:"to@mail.com"}} at end of to recipients of theMessage
make new recipient with properties {email address:{address:"to@mail.com"}} at end of cc recipients of theMessage
open theMessage
end tell
```

I would like to add a line that picks one of several POP accounts to send from.

Ideally the resulting mail has the signature stored under that address.